# PDF file is opening in same window, but I want to open it as a seperate file

Tags: java, pdf, servlets

PDF file is opening in same window, but I want to open it as a seperate file without *Save As* dialog box.

Here is a relevant piece of servlet code:

```
response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=_blank_");
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setContentLength(baos.size());
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
baos.writeTo(out);
out.flush();
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You have two possibilities:

1. `Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=foo.pdf`
2. `Content-Disposition: inline;filename=foo.pdf`

The first prompts the user for saving the file and the dialog is browser dependent, you cannot do much about it from a server side script. The second opens the pdf inside the browser if there's a registered program capable of doing this like Adobe Reader.

Comment: Put a `target="_blank"` to the link or open it in a new popup window.

Answer (score 0):

You ask this question long back , may be till now you got ans of your question. I was facing same issue and my requirement was to open PDF file in separate window.  Whatever suggestion given in response is good . I want to add few more lines.

In servlet you shoud add below code 
 **webAppAccess.getHttpServletResponse().setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=printReport.pdf");**

and in jsp file

```
**window.open('PrintReportConsumer?operation=getShortReport&customerNumber=400000852&relationNumber=400000852&fromDate=29-Jun-2012&toDate=02-Jul-2012&languageId=en&language=en');**
```